# Broadcast receiver change UI

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, broadcastreceiver

I have searched widely but not found an answer to this question:
Is it possible to change a variable in a Jetpack compose user interface from a broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't modify your compose ui from Broadcast receiver directly. Instead, your Broadcast receiver should change some data in your data layer - datastore, preferences, database or just in memory in some Repository singleton class. Then you should make this data observable and observe them from your compose ui.

Comment: can you know any example using using broadcast receiver in data layer ?

Comment: Its the other way around, you use data layer in broadcast receiver. You can for example update your shared preferences from broadcast receiver, that's what I mean.

Comment: Ohh now I understand it

Answer (score 11):

You can make use of `DisposableEffect` and `LocalContext.current` for register and unregister your `BroadcastReceiver` in compose. Remeber to use `rememberUpdatedState` for keep an updated reference to the lambda

Here is an example of a generic `BroadcastReceiver` in compose

```kotlin
@Composable
fun SystemBroadcastReceiver(
    systemAction: String,
    onSystemEvent: (intent: Intent?) -> Unit
) {
    val context = LocalContext.current

    val currentOnSystemEvent by rememberUpdatedState( onSystemEvent )

    DisposableEffect(context, systemAction){

        val intentFilter = IntentFilter( systemAction )

        val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver(){
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                currentOnSystemEvent( intent )
            }
        }

        context.registerReceiver( receiver, intentFilter)

        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is an example of how I used it to extract an OTP:

```kotlin
// this is the value I want to change
var myOtp : String by remember{ mutableStateOf("") }

SystemBroadcastReceiver(systemAction = SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION){ intent ->
    if( intent?.action == SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION ){

        val extras = intent.extras
        val status = extras?.get( EXTRA_STATUS) as? Status

        if( status?.statusCode == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS){
            val message = extras.getString(EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE, "")

            val otpReceived = Regex("[0-9]{6}").find( message )?.value

            if( otpReceived != null ){

                // here i change the value of "myOtp" !!
                myOtp = otpReceived
            }
        }
    }
}
```

here is link of the above example:

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/migrate/interoperability-apis/views-in-compose#case-study-broadcastreceivers

Comment: context.registerReceiver() & context.unregisterReceiver() didn't worked for me. BroadcastReceiver was getting register and unregister but onReceive() method did not triggered. I change it to LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).registerReceiver() & LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(ctx).unregisterReceiver() then only it worked.